# Random boolean to switch not working

Tags: geometry-nodes

i want to randomly select from 2 different geometries. this should be possible with a random value node that has the type boolean. however, i just won't work and the line connecting the 2 is always red.

does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
[image: GN]

It must works.

You can change the 'seed' value to obtain a diferent result.

I hope it helps :)

[image]

Comment: this seems really complex. do you have an idea why my approach does not work?

Comment: In the field 'ID' of 'Random' you must put an integer.

Comment: that worked. thanks

Comment: Wait, what ? You don't need this complex setup, instead switch the Random Value type from *float* to *boolean*. It will output True and False

Comment: Totally true, I gave you an example to explain how it works